# Angular 4 how do I disable tab navigation in an angular material tab group?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I have a tab-group but I don't want the user to be able to change to the next form without filling the required controls first. Instead, I would like the user to only be able to navigate using a next and back buttons that I will enable disable based on validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it by using the following css

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9oZIF87yqRUWVOt3ymbt?p=preview)**